# How to stash and unstash artefacts across stages in a Jenkinsfile in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have 2 stages in a Jenkinsfile with decarative pipeline

```
stage("Build_Stage") {
  steps {
    sh './build.sh 2>&1 ; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0'
    // The output directory is ./build. How to stash this here
  }
}
stage("Upload_Artefacts_Stage") {
  steps {
    // How to unstash the build directory which was stashed in Build_Stage
    sh './prepare_build_artefacts.sh ios 2>&1 ; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0'
  }
}
```

`prepare_build_artefacts.sh` intakes the output of `build.sh` which is called across stages.

How to stash the output build directory and un-stash it in the second stage which follows the build stage?

Comment: Are you asking about: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build

Comment: Yes. Exactly @MattSchuchard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see below code which will help you to stash and unstash.Note that the stash and unstash steps are designed for use with small files. For large data transfers, use the External Workspace Manager plugin, or use an external repository manager such as Nexus or Artifactory

```
stage("Build_Stage") {
  steps {
    sh './build.sh 2>&1 ; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0'
    // The output directory is ./build. How to stash this here
    // Below method will stash build directory 
    stash includes: "build/" , name: "Build_stash"
  }
}
stage("Upload_Artefacts_Stage") {
  steps {
    // How to unstash the build directory which was stashed in Build_Stage
    // Give path of the directory where you would like to unstash it.
    dir("C:\\Data\\CI_Workspace\\${env.JOB_NAME}")
    {
        unstash "Build_stash"
    }
    sh './prepare_build_artefacts.sh ios 2>&1 ; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0'
  }
}
```